# Getting Error for updating a row in a table using EF

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting this below error when I try to update a row in my table using Entity Framework.
I am able to add a new entry to table but not able to update the existing entry.

Error:-
The specified value is not an instance of type 'Edm.Decimal'\r\nParameter name: value

And my table has all the columns of type (nvarchar,char,bit,numeric,uniqueidentifier,int)
I dont even have a column of type Decimal. I dont know where this is coming from.

I am using ASP.NET MVC3 and Entity Framework. I have checked the table mapping with the Entity Framework and it looks fine.

Please help me.

Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: Can you post some code?  That might help someone help you with this.

Comment: what type of database you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The Identity column of the table was type Numeric. It should have been type Big Int. I updated the type of column and it has worked. 
Thanks,
Vivek